# What is the bug in this code

Tags: java, testing

I was reading on the importance of testing and as an example this code appeared:

```
public Scheme join(final Scheme other) {
    final HashSet<Attribute> $ = new HashSet<Attribute>();

    for (int i = 0; i < attributes.length; ++i)
        $.add(attributes[i]);

    for (int i = 0; i < attributes.length; ++i)
        $.add(other.attributes[i]);
    return new Scheme(true, $.toArray(new Attribute[$.size()]));
}
```

and it said it has a bug in Scehme.join()
but I can't see one!

Comment: One observation on the $ sign: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html

Comment: It is not a bug, but the code's quality is really bad.

Comment: it's legal for variable names - it's not a bug

Comment: Can't you use `{} brackets` in for loop, it's became hard to handle when code increases.

Comment: who said there is error and what it exactly says?

Comment: it was in a material I was reading with only this info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bug is in your second loop:

```
// Here ------------v
for (int i = 0; i < attributes.length; ++i)
    $.add(other.attributes[i]);
```

That should be `other.attributes`, not `attributes`.

---

This is a great example of why using the enhanced `for` loop is a good idea:

```
public Scheme join(final Scheme other) {
    final HashSet<Attribute> $ = new HashSet<Attribute>();

    for (Attribute attr : attributes) {
        $.add(attr);
    }

    for (Attribute attr : other.attributes) {
        $.add(attr);
    }

    return new Scheme(true, $.toArray(new Attribute[$.size()]));
}
```

Comment: thank you, it was a typo, I tried to copy it but it didn't work. I guess it was an example of the disadvantages of code duplication.

Answer (score 1):

my guess wille be here

`final HashSet<attribute> $ = new HashSet<Attribute>();`

on left hand side you have `attribute` and on right hand side `Attribute`, and as java is case sensitive language, this are two different objects

Comment: sorry that was a typo

Comment: @Siham, then have a look at `T.J. Crowder` answer